# why is process.start() return null

Tags: c#

```
pdfProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.Combine(FilePath, FileName + ".pdf"))
```

On my computer it returns the correct process, but when I run it on another computer it returns null. ps:the pdf is opened by edge correctly.

When I change the code to:

```
pdfProcess = Process.Start(psi)  //the psi is a StartInfo class
```

the `pdfProcess` is the wrong process, which has exception "No process is associated with this object".

How can I get correct process?

Comment: Can you open a PDF on this "*another*" pc ? I'm wondering if your path is wrong (very likely), or there is no default program associated with a pdf.

Comment: Why is this even a question? The documentation clearly states: _"A new Process that is associated with the process resource, **or null if no process resource is started.**"_ [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-6.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_)

Comment: It sounds like the other computer does not have a default program associated with PDF files. This may also be a problem for the specific user-account running the program, as there are "global" file associations (system), and then user-defined file associations. If you're not able to open a file, see if something like Edge or Chrome or Adobe Reader is installed and associated with the ".pdf" file extension.

Comment: You should be able to open the pdf with something like "path.to.pdfReader" "path.to.pdf"

Comment: You get null, and no exception, when no process *needed* to get started to handle the pdf file.  This is the behavior of Explorer, a single-instance process.  Presumably the user has an extension installed that gives Explorer the ability to display pdf files.  There is no practical way to track what happens next.

Comment: On another computer, I can open it with the Edge. And the process is starting,that's the stranger part.